# Is Lab Management feature available in cloud-based Team Foundation Service?

Tags: tfs

There is a cloud-based version of Microsoft Team Foundation Server, that is named as "Team Foundation Service". Is the Lab Management feature available in this cloud-based service?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hello It's not disponible for this moment

1 you can test here : http://tfspreview.com/

It is one of the future developments

Answer (score 2):

You can use CloudShare, a cloud service that allows you to create lab management environments in the cloud with Team Foundation Service.
http://www.cloudshare.com/

Comment: I can't find anything about TFS at their website :(

Comment: I saw a demo of their service but you are right there isn't much info on TFS.  Under the blog there is some information but it is more around SharePoint dev.  http://blog.cloudshare.com/2012/06/18/using-tfs-service-preview-for-sharepoint-team-development-with-cloudshare/

Comment: You should be able to creat standard environments using virtual machines hosted in Azure as well.  CloudShare is a great solution also.

Comment: I'm interested in an integration of lab management with other TFS features, such as test management. For example, to configure automatic execution of TFS test plans on different virtual environments, and collect test execution data (intelli trace, video of UI tests, logs, exception details, etc) from virtual machines to TFS test controller.